# How I know the BodyFormat property after decrypting Pgp message using redemption

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, outlook-redemption, openpgp

I am trying to decrypt a MSG file for a message that is originally in HTML format but encrypted using Symentec Encryption Desktop (an outlook plugin used to encrypt PGP messages).

looking at the Mapi properties of the encrypted message, i am seeing that it is set as a plain text formatted message. Perhaps it due to the encryption process.

I'm using bouncy castle library to decrypt the message, but I can't find how I can know the actual format after the message is decrypted, whether it is in plain text or HTML or RTf.

For example, in Smime, when decrypt a message we get meta information regarding the properties of the decrypted contents. is there an equivalent information available in PGP specification, that we can use to determine the original format of the message body.

I am asking this because, I manually trying to set the decrypted body into PR_Body mapi property, or what ever mapi properties needs to be set.

Any Help please.

Comment: What data do you get after decrypting? a MIME file?

Comment: Hello Dimity, No, Actually If the message HTML I get a HTML File, if it is a plain text, I get a plain text, and if it's a RTF, I get RTF Formatted body. I can share screen shots if you need.

Comment: I am confused - if you get HTML, set the HTMLBody, if plain text - Body property.

Comment: this is exactly what I do. and also if it is RTF I set the RTFBody. but my question is how can I know the body format after decrypting the message in order to set the right Mapi property. did you understand me Dmitry ?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean... If no other properties are available, look at the first character - it will be '{" for RTF and '<' for HTML

Comment: ya, that's a good solution. but, I am afraid that the original body message has either "{" or "<" and I cannot determine correctly the body format. but anyway Thank you so much my friend. I thought there is another MAPI property that can help me to know the body format before inserting it.

Comment: I don't know, I never had to deal with Symentec Encryption Desktop. Do you see an other MAPI properties in OutlookSpy?

Comment: Ya, I checked all the MAPI properties using MFC Mapi. while the message is encrypted it shows me that the PR_MSG_EDITOR_FORMAT is Plain text even if the message in RTF Format or HTML Format. and I cannot detect the actual format after decrypting it. I though OpenPGP is going to help me and provide me some metadata but it didn't.